# Trouble with clearing other text boxes when value is backspaced

Tags: javascript

I am a beginner at Javascript, this is my first Javascript that isn't just 'cut/paste/hack'. I created an calculator that updates the output as input is typed, I can get all my 'answerboxes' to clear when the input box is blurred then focused, but if I backspace the value out of the input box the 'answerboxes' still show the 'answers' based on the last char. value that was backspaced.

In my 'validiateTheInput' funct. I can declare an 'if = "3"' to clear them and it works when a '3' is the value (which would not work in the end :) ), but I can't seem to catch it if the field appears blank do to user backspacing the value from the box.

Am I obsessing over something stupid, or am I just missing something?

Heres the whole thing (with some basic HTML ommitted):
There is also a bit of overkill in the validation function because I was experimenting with trying to catch the 'blank input' do to backspacing.

```
//jQuery keyup to grab input
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#totalFeet').keyup(function() {
        validiateTheInput();
    });
});

//clear calculated values    


function clearBoxes(answerbox, answerbox1, answerbox2, totalFeetField) {
    answerbox.value = "";
    answerbox1.value = "";
    answerbox2.value = "";
    totalFeetField.value = "";
};

//validate input, then go to callAll (calc the output and display it)


function validiateTheInput() {
    var totalFeetField = document.getElementById('totalFeet');
    var answerbox = document.getElementById('answerbox').value;
    var answerbox1 = document.getElementById('answerbox1').value;
    var answerbox2 = document.getElementById('answerbox2').value;

    // feel like I should be able to catch it here with the length prop.
    if (totalFeetField.value.length == 0) {
        clearBoxes(answerbox, answerbox1, answerbox2, totalFeetField);
    }

    // if input is usable, do the good stuff...
    if (totalFeetField.value != "" && !isNaN(totalFeetField.value)) {
        callAll(); // call the function that calcs the boxes, etc.
    }

    // if input is NaN then alert and clear boxes (clears because a convenient blur event happens)
    else if (isNaN(totalFeetField.value)) {
        alert("The Total Sq. Footage Value must be a number!")
        document.getElementById('totalFeet').value = "";
    }

    // clears the input box (I wish) if you backspace the val. to nothing
    else if (totalFeetField.value == '3') {
        clearBoxes(answerbox, answerbox1, answerbox2, totalFeetField);
    }
    // extra effort trying to catch that empty box :(   
    else if (typeof totalFeetField.value == 'undefined' || totalFeetField.value === null || totalFeetField.value === '') clearBoxes(answerbox, answerbox1, answerbox2, totalFeetField);
}


//group all box calc functions for easy inline call


function callAll() {
    calcFirstBox();
    calcSecondBox();
    calcThirdBox();
}

// calculate box fields based on input box


function calcFirstBox() {
    var totalFeetField = document.getElementById('totalFeet');
    var answer = totalFeetField.value * 5.95; // set multiplier
    document.getElementById('answerbox').value = answer.toFixed(2);
}

// calc the second box


function calcSecondBox() {
    var totalFeetField = document.getElementById('totalFeet');
    var answer = totalFeetField.value * 18.95; // set multiplier
    document.getElementById('answerbox1').value = answer.toFixed(2);
}

// calc the third box


function calcThirdBox() {
    var totalFeetField = document.getElementById('totalFeet');
    var answer = totalFeetField.value * 25.95; // set multiplier
    document.getElementById('answerbox2').value = answer.toFixed(2);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="calculator">

        <form name="calculate">
            <label for="total">Total Value to Calculate:</label> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
            <input id="totalFeet" type="text" name="total" size="15" onfocus="clearBoxes(totalFeet, answerbox, answerbox1, answerbox2);"><br /><br />


            <label for="answerbox">Total Value X &nbsp;$5.95:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$</label>
            <input id="answerbox" onfocus="this.blur();" type="text" name="answerbox" size="15"><br /><br />

            <label for="answerbox1">Total Value X $18.95:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$</label>
            <input id="answerbox1" onfocus="this.blur();" type="text" name="answerbox1" size="15"><br /><br />

            <label for="answerbox2">Total Value X $25.95:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$</label>
            <input id="answerbox2" onfocus="this.blur();" type="text" name="answerbox2" size="15">
        </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not storing the element objects in variables - you're storing their values:

```
var answerbox = document.getElementById('answerbox').value;
var answerbox1 = document.getElementById('answerbox1').value;
var answerbox2 = document.getElementById('answerbox2').value;
```

...so later, when you call the following function, passing these variables as an argument:

```
clearBoxes(answerbox, answerbox1, answerbox2, totalFeetField);
```

...you're not passing the elements.  You can fix it by removing `.value` off each line in your variable assignments.

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/Mq6uN/**

Side note and shameless plug: if you want something a little more robust than `keyup` for detecting input, check out [this blog post](http://whattheheadsaid.com/2010/09/effectively-detecting-user-input-in-javascript).

Comment: Thanks so much! I gonna read your post too, because I am looking for various ways of enhancing the keyup. My next move was/is supposed to throw some fade effects on the output boxes so to be a bit more smooth in appearance :)

Comment: @rhaag: I forgot to mention, there's also a jQuery plugin a few posts later that normalizes the `input` event I discuss in the linked post for Internet Explorer.  Good luck :-)

Comment: The blog post is excellent! It totally explains why (this morning) when I tried to add a fadeIn to the output that it didn't work, and when experimenting w/ a fadeOut (as a debugging move) it would fade out at the wrong moment (it also faded out the whole textbox...wrong selector!). Your blog made me remember reading about the difference of keyUp/keyDown (keyUp is where I tried the fadeIn). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the value of answerbox, answerbox1 etc to the clearBoxes function, not the elements themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a full jQuery approach:

```
//jQuery keyup to grab input
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id$=totalFeet]').keyup(function () {
            validiateTheInput();
        });
        function clearBoxes() {
            $('input[id$=answerbox]').val("");
            $('input[id$=answerbox1]').val("");
            $('input[id$=answerbox2]').val("");
        }
        //validate input, then go to callAll (calc the output and display it)
        function validiateTheInput() {
            var totalFeetField = $('input[id$=totalFeet]').val();
            var answerbox = $('input[id$=answerbox]').val();
            var answerbox1 = $('input[id$=answerbox1]').val();
            var answerbox2 = $('input[id$=answerbox2]').val();

            // feel like I should be able to catch it here with the length prop.
            if (totalFeetField == "") {
                clearBoxes();
            }

            // if input is usable, do the good stuff...
            if (totalFeetField != "" && !isNaN(totalFeetField)) {
                callAll(); // call the function that calcs the boxes, etc.
            }

            // if input is NaN then alert and clear boxes (clears because a convenient blur event happens)
            else if (isNaN(totalFeetField)) {
                alert("The Total Sq. Footage Value must be a number!")
                $('input[id$=totalFeet]').val(""); 
            }

            // clears the input box (I wish) if you backspace the val. to nothing
            else if (totalFeetField == '3') {
                clearBoxes();
            }
            // extra effort trying to catch that empty box :(   
            else if (typeof totalFeetField == 'undefined' || totalFeetField === null || totalFeetField === '')
                clearBoxes();
        }
        //group all box calc functions for easy inline call
        function callAll() {
            calcFirstBox();
            calcSecondBox();
            calcThirdBox();
        }

        // calculate box fields based on input box
        function calcFirstBox() {
            var totalFeetField = $('input[id$=totalFeet]').val(); 
            var answer = totalFeetField * 5.95; // set multiplier

            $('input[id$=answerbox]').val(answer.toFixed(2));
        }

        // calc the second box
        function calcSecondBox() {
            var totalFeetField = $('input[id$=totalFeet]').val(); 
            var answer = totalFeetField * 18.95; // set multiplier

            $('input[id$=answerbox1]').val(answer.toFixed(2));
        }

        // calc the third box
        function calcThirdBox() {
            var totalFeetField = $('input[id$=totalFeet]').val(); 
            var answer = totalFeetField * 25.95; // set multiplier

            $('input[id$=answerbox2]').val(answer.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
```

Also, here's the HTML

```
<form name="calculate" action="">
        <label for="total">Total Value to Calculate:</label> &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp 
        <input id="totalFeet" type="text" name="total" size="15" onfocus="clearBoxes();"/><br /><br />


        <label for="answerbox">Total Value X &nbsp;$5.95:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$</label>
        <input id="answerbox" onfocus="this.blur();" type="text" name="answerbox" size="15"/><br /><br />

        <label for="answerbox1">Total Value X $18.95:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$</label>
        <input id="answerbox1" onfocus="this.blur();" type="text" name="answerbox1" size="15"/><br /><br />

        <label for="answerbox2">Total Value X $25.95:&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp$</label>
        <input id="answerbox2" onfocus="this.blur();" type="text" name="answerbox2" size="15"/>
    </form>
```

Sometimes mixing jQuery and plain javascript doesn't work too well. This code should work in clearing your textboxes when the first textbox is empty. It also works on number validation.

Comment: *"Sometimes mixing jQuery and plain javascript doesn't work too well"* - I don't wish to be rude, but you don't provide a great argument for this; your jQuery selectors are pretty horrible.  For a start, why are you using the "attribute ends with" selector for unique IDs?  Secondly, you don't do any caching of jQuery objects so you're potentially running this poor performing selector several times and, finally, your code isn't particularly shorter than the OP's original JavaScript.  Mixing the right amounts of JavaScript and jQuery is definitely advised to maximise performance and efficiency.

Comment: Thanks very much for you reply, I had the inclination to cleanup the inline call, but it didn't work this morning :) I haven't studied your post in full yet, but wouldn't this make it a little easier for me to apply jquery effects now?

Comment: @Andy E: You're right about caching jQuery objects. I forgot to do that. Also, about my selectors, I use those with ASP .NET as ASP .NET adds extra information to the id tags that normal selectors like $(#section .control) don't always pickup on. I know the OP wasn't using ASP .NET, but it's just out of habit that I used those selectors. My apologies too for making a statement about the mixing of jQuery and javascript.